# Why Capybara signout user before finish the test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I am implementing an update feature spec using Capybara and Factory_bot, before starting the test, I signed in with `#login_as` method successfully, after that all fields filled with `#fill_in` method, but when `#click_on` method clicks on `Update` button , user sign out , and I cannot get the result after updating, so test failed!.

My Rspec code

```
`require 'rails_helper'
   #Update user test 
   RSpec.describe 'Updating a user', type: :feature do
     let(:tester1) { FactoryBot.create(:user, name: "tester1",
                                        email: "tester1@gmail.com",
                                        password: "password")}

     before do
       login_as(tester1, :scope => :user)
     end

     scenario 'ubdate with valid name' do
       visit edit_user_registration_path(tester1)
       fill_in 'Email', with: 'new_tester1@gmail.com'
       sleep(3)
       fill_in 'Password', with: 'password'
       sleep(3)
       fill_in "user_password_confirmation", with: 'password'
       sleep(3)
       fill_in "user_current_password", with: 'password'
       sleep(3)
       click_on "Update"
       sleep(3)
       expect(page).to have_content('Your account has been updated successfully.')
       sleep(3)
     end
   end`
```

Failures:

```
       1) Updating a user ubdate with valid name
         Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Your account has been updated 
    successfully.')
         expected to find text "Your account has been updated successfully." in "FACEBOOK CLONE\nHome\nHelp\nLog_in\nSign Up\n×\nYou need to sign in or sign up before continuing.\nLog in\nEmail\nPassword\nRemember me on this computer\nSign up\nForgot your password?\nFacebook Clone\nAbout\nContact\nNews"`
```

Comment: How is your `login_as` implemented? If you do `visit edit_user_registration_path(tester1)` without the `login_as` can you still fill in the fields?

Comment: `login_as` is available by including Warden test helpers :
 `#spec/rails_helper
    .
    .
    .
    config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
    .
    .
    .`
- Yes I can login ,fill fields ,submit and redirect.